# Why my html doesn't recognize angular tags?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-material, web-frontend

My html does mot recognize angular tags , i install angular in my web solution  , ,i registered in bundles , i add those to my layout

```
  <link href="~/Content/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="~/Content/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

my angular bundles

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular")
              .Include("~/Scripts/angular.js",
              "~/Scripts/angular-aria/angular-aria.js",
              "~/Scripts/angular-animate/angular-animate.js",
              "~/Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.js"));
```

and i injected to my application

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("app.controllers", []);

    var dependencies = [
        "ngRoute",
        "app.controllers",
        "ngMaterial"
    ];

    angular.module("app", dependencies)
    .config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/users", { templateUrl: "Frontend/views/users.html", controller: "usersCtrl" })
            .when("/user/add", { templateUrl: "Frontend/views/userAdd.html", controller: "userAddCtrl" })
            .when("/user/:id", { templateUrl: "Frontend/views/userDetails.html", controller: "userDetailsCtrl" })
            .when("/user/edit/:id", { templateUrl: "Frontend/views/userEdit.html", controller: "userEditCtrl" })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/users"
        });
    }]).run(function () {

    });
}())
```

however when i write a tag angular in my partial html it's says for example
"Cannot resolve tag md-content"

Comment: Is this an error coming from your IDE or from the actual page?

Comment: Please show the tag that is not recognized (the relevant HTML)

Comment: Try to install it from Package Manager Console: `Install-Package AngularJS` rather than copy them from external source, or reference all AngularJS script in main layout page with `@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")`.

Comment: You are setting 2 angular-material scripts and no angular-animate

Comment: @charlietfl is an error from ide , i put in layout     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular") , i add     <script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
 but nothing seems to work

Comment: Forget about ide...what errors show in browser

Comment: @charlietfl Nothing in my browser

Comment: OK...so if no error in browser issue is ide related. Update ide to allow unknown tags for that project